# Why isn't there a JTextField being displayed here?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield

```
public class WASD extends JFrame{
Ellipse2D.Double ball;
int ballx = 100;
int bally = 100;
static JTextField typingArea;
public static void main(String[] args){ 
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
private static void createAndShowGUI(){
    WASD frame = new WASD("frame");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.addComponentsToPane();

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
private void addComponentsToPane(){
    typingArea = new JTextField(20);
    //typingArea.addKeyListener(this);
}
public WASD(String name){
    super(name);
}
}
```

When I run the program all I get is an empty window. The JTextField doesn't show up. Thanks!

(Apparently my post has too much code, so I'm adding this to make it let me submit. Ignore this sentence and the previous one.)

Comment: try adding this to your addComponentsToPane() method:   frame.add(typingArea);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `JTextField` needs to also be added to the frame after it is created.

```
private void addComponentsToPane(){
    typingArea = new JTextField(20);
    frame.add(typingArea);
}
```

Comment: I asked this on another forum and they gave me a similar answer. The "frame." part was what I was missing! Thanks!